# How to get value in from Array in JS when I get array like this [["a","b","c"]]

Tags: javascript, arrays, retool

I have object like this:

[image]

and I need an array like this

["scan7","scan59","umowa"]

my array is query22.data

but I use Retool and at the end I get array in array which has one element. -> [["scan7","scan59","umowa"]]

In the Retool I get something like this
[image]

[image]

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Your first image is an array in the form `["scan7","scan59","umowa"]`, it's just showing you the index of each item in the array.

Answer (score -2):

Your first image is showing an array already. Remember the sign `[]` after `file_name`, it means the data type is an array.

Comment: Ok, I'm aware that it's still an array, but I was more concerned with how to solve this problem so it's correct

Comment: you can use `query22.data.flat()`